# Disabling all builds after migrating Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, startup

I am in the process of migrating a Jenkins server from an internal resource to AWS EC2. I have completed the copying of all files in /var/lib/jenkins. However, when I start Jenkins it immediately wants to run builds, and they all fail because I need to make some changes. Devs don't like the tons of emails.

How do I **start** Jenkins with all jobs/builds disabled by default, so I can test and configure things before cutting over to the new server installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a useful [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+all+jobs)!  This groovy script needs to be placed in $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy